# DataFrame Transformation | A Better Way?

Tags: python, pandas

The way I went about to transform my DataFrame to add columns that are derived from existing data seemed pretty painful.  At first, I considered using apply, but I realized that these additional columns hinged on certain aspects of my original DataFrame (e.g. the MMR information was unique to the "ReplayID" and whether the team won or not as found in "Is Winner").  I found a way forward, but I'm wondering if there was a more efficient way to go about it.  The DataFrames are below and my code below those:

**Before Transformation**

[image: Before Transformation]

**After Transformation**

[image: After Transformation]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('small.csv', index_col=False)
del df['Unnamed: 0']

replayGroup = df['MMR Before'].groupby([df['ReplayID'], df['Is Winner']])
summaryReplayGroup = replayGroup.agg([np.max, np.mean, np.min, np.std])

# i[0] -> Index
# i[1] -> ReplayID
# i[2] -> Is Auto Select
# i[3] -> HeroID
# i[4] -> Hero Level
# i[5] -> Is Winner
# i[6] -> MMR Before
maxMMR = []
meanMMR = []
minMMR = []
stdMMR = []

for i in df.itertuples():
    key = (i[1], i[5])
    maxMMR.append(summaryReplayGroup.loc[key]['amax'])
    meanMMR.append(summaryReplayGroup.loc[key]['mean'])
    minMMR.append(summaryReplayGroup.loc[key]['amin'])
    stdMMR.append(summaryReplayGroup.loc[key]['std'])

df['Max Team MMR'] = maxMMR
df['Mean Team MMR'] = meanMMR
df['Min Team MMR'] = minMMR
df['Std Team MMR'] = stdMMR

# Negative diff indicates disadvantage
maxDiffMMR = []
meanDiffMMR = []
minDiffMMR = []
stdDiffMMR = []

# i[0] -> Index
# i[1] -> ReplayID
# i[2] -> Is Auto Select
# i[3] -> HeroID
# i[4] -> Hero Level
# i[5] -> Is Winner
# i[6] -> MMR Before
# i[7] -> Max Team MMR
# i[8] -> Mean Team MMR
# i[9] -> Min Team MMR
# i[10] -> Std Team MMR
for i in df.itertuples():
    if i[5]:
        opposite = 0
    else:
        opposite = 1

    replayId = i[1]

    oppTeamMaxMMR = df.loc[df['ReplayID'] == replayId].loc[df['Is Winner'] == opposite]['Max Team MMR'].mean()
    teamMaxMMR = i[7]
    diffMaxMMR = teamMaxMMR - oppTeamMaxMMR
    oppTeamMeanMMR = df.loc[df['ReplayID'] == replayId].loc[df['Is Winner'] == opposite]['Mean Team MMR'].mean()
    teamMeanMMR = i[8]
    diffMeanMMR = teamMeanMMR - oppTeamMeanMMR
    oppTeamMinMMR = df.loc[df['ReplayID'] == replayId].loc[df['Is Winner'] == opposite]['Min Team MMR'].mean()
    teamMinMMR = i[8]
    diffMinMMR = teamMinMMR - oppTeamMinMMR
    oppTeamStdMMR = df.loc[df['ReplayID'] == replayId].loc[df['Is Winner'] == opposite]['Std Team MMR'].mean()
    teamStdMMR = i[9]
    diffStdMMR = teamStdMMR - oppTeamStdMMR

    maxDiffMMR.append(diffMaxMMR)
    meanDiffMMR.append(diffMeanMMR)
    minDiffMMR.append(diffMinMMR)
    stdDiffMMR.append(diffStdMMR)

df['Diff Max MMR'] = maxDiffMMR
df['Diff Mean MMR'] = meanDiffMMR
df['Diff Min MMR'] = minDiffMMR
df['Diff Std MMR'] = stdDiffMMR
```

Thanks for taking the time to look!

Comment: Major criticism!  This sort of question is interesting but!!! you posted a picture instead of data we can copy and paste.  I know how to help you but I have to do tons of work to produce the example.  So much better if you post data or code that recreates data.  Help me, help you!

Comment: Sorry, just have a question. This looks like the LoL data dump I saw posted on Reddit a few days prior. What is the purpose of your study, I'm curious? Thanks!

Comment: @piRSquared - excellent criticism and well received - I'll be sure to do that in the future!

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy This is actually a Heroes of the Storm data dump =)  I'm doing a tailored exercise to get acquainted with Machine Learning by using the summary statistics on MMR to predict the outcome of a game!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df3` is your final dataframe

```
funcs = {
    'Max Team MMR': 'max',
    'Mean Team MMR': 'mean',
    'Min Team MMR': 'min',
    'Std Team MMR': 'std'
}

idx_cols = ['ReplayID', 'Is Winner']
val_col = 'MMR Before'

df1 = df.set_index(idx_cols)
summaryReplayGroup = df1[val_col].groupby(level=idx_cols).agg(funcs)

df2 = df1.join(summaryReplayGroup)

diffs = summaryReplayGroup.unstack(idx_cols[0]).diff().dropna().squeeze().unstack(0)
diffs.columns = diffs.columns.str.replace(r'(.+) Team', r'Diff \1')
diffs = pd.concat([diffs, -diffs], keys=[1, 0])

df3 = df2.reset_index().join(diffs, on=idx_cols[::-1])
df3
```

***results***

[image]

***setup***
for others to try

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [57010496, 0, 36,  9, 0, 2589],
        [57010496, 0, 20,  9, 1, 2354],
        [57010496, 0, 14,  6, 1, 2314],
        [57010496, 0, 12, 10, 0, 2288],
        [57010496, 0, 39, 10, 0, 2486],
        [57010496, 0, 19, 10, 1, 2292],
        [57010496, 0, 27,  9, 1, 2385],
        [57010496, 0, 11,  7, 0, 2183],
        [57010496, 0, 24,  9, 1, 2471],
        [57010496, 0, 35,  3, 0, 2166],
        [57010518, 0, 22,  4, 0, 2582],
        [57010518, 0, 29,  6, 1, 2470],
        [57010518, 0, 36,  8, 1, 2590],
        [57010518, 0, 31,  9, 1, 2313],
        [57010518, 0, 19,  8, 1, 2159],
        [57010518, 0, 13,  7, 0, 1996],
        [57010518, 0,  7,  6, 1, 2441],
        [57010518, 0, 21,  7, 0, 2220],
        [57010518, 0, 42,  9, 0, 2465],
        [57010518, 0, 18, 11, 0, 2392],
    ], columns=['ReplayID', 'Is Auto Select', 'HeroID',
                'Hero Level', 'Is Winner', 'MMR Before'])
```

Comment: This is wonderful!  Thank you so much!  It's given me a lot of new methods to dive into and become more and more familiar with.

Comment: @Joe glad I could help